# Add object to another object property in JS

Tags: javascript

```
obj={
  cats:{name:"kitty",age:"8"}
}
```

I need to add `{name:"nacy",age:"12"}` to `obj.cats` how I can do that?

What I tried:

```
Object.assign({name:"nacy",age:"12"},obj.cats);
```

This doesn't do anything, when I `console.log(obj)` I got kitty only.

In the end I want when I `console.log(obj.cats)` to get this:

```
{name:"kitty",age:"8"}, {name:"nacy",age:"12"}
```

And I don't want to use arrays.

Comment: Objects must have unique keys. What should your final object look like? Are you sure you don't want an array?

Comment: I updated the question, I don't want to deal with arrays just yet because I'm just learning and I really want to figure this out with just objects. thanks.

Comment: This isn't going to work with objects. `cats:{name:"kitty",age:"8"}, {name:"nacy",age:"12"}` is not valid javascript. `cats:[{name:"kitty",age:"8"}, {name:"nacy",age:"12"}]` is, but that's because it's an array.

Comment: oooh okay, I see now. thanks I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be advisable to read more the documentation on objects and arrays. `object.cats` should be an array. Correct usage:

```js
let obj = {
  cats: [
    {name:"kitty",age:"8"}
  ]
};

obj.cats.push({name:"nacy",age:"12"})

//Now here, we have 2 elements of obj.cats
console.log(obj.cats)
```

If you want to use objects and replace obj.cats (as your example), you must first pass the existing object, and then the value to replace: `Object.assign(obj.cats, {name:"nacy",age:"12"})`

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna add 'nacy' first you have change `cats` to become an array
(read more about array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

it looks like this:

```
var obj={
    cats:[{name:"kitty",age:"8"}]
}
```

and then 'push' or add 'nacy'

```
obj.cats.push({name:"nacy",age:"12"})
```

result :

```
{ cats: [ { name: 'kitty', age: '8' }, { name: 'nacy', age: '12' } ] }
```